# imacros can't save html page build with flash application

Tags: javascript, html, flash, imacros

I want to save some html pages that are built with flash application. The structure of each page is something like that (description is extremely simplified) :

Javascript : var str = '0123456789ABCDEFGH' (in fact a very long base64 string)

The flash application decripts the base64 string and makes some transformations, such that finally the desired web page is displayed.

The imacros is the following :

```
VERSION BUILD=7500718 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://static.bacalaureat.edu.ro/2013/rapoarte/rezultate/alfabetic/page_5.html
SAVEAS TYPE=CPL FOLDER=D:\Student\Downl FILE=B0001
```

Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome cannot execute the last command, although the page is displayed correctly.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem ?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
VERSION BUILD=7500718 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=http://static.bacalaureat.edu.ro/2013/rapoarte/rezultate/alfabetic/page_5.html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=CLASS:* EXTRACT=HTM
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\ FILE=B0001.txt
```

I tried this and it worked.

http://pastebin.com/uHrxMidy